# Really strong beer's gravity (1.120) won't drop below 1.042

Tags: beer, first-time-brewer, brewing, alcohol-content

I've brewed my second beer, it's starting gravity was 1120. It didn't seem to want to get a gravity below 1050 after 9 days, so i added champagne yeast. Two days later it dropped down to 1042. 4 days later it's still 1042. What's wrong with this if anything? Or does anyone think it will drop more? And do i want it to drop more?

Comment: Which yeast you used in the first place? Did you made a yeast starter? How much quantity you pitch in?

Comment: "I've brewed/brewing my second beer it starting gravity was 1120" - Yeah, that's a terrible idea, kinda like trying to run a marathon the very first time you've ever worked out. Your chances at a succesful, tasty, high-gravity brew are really, really low. I suggest you learn the basics of regular brewing first, and work your way up that high later on.

Comment: yeast starters save beers!

Comment: Also, what was the recipe like? From what source(s) did you get those 1.120 gravity points? Malt extract? Mashed grain? Sugar? Honey?

Comment: then recipe 1.7kg beer makers old 1.7kg black rock light malt 12.5 grams holdings hops 11.5 grams dry ale yeast to 12 litres 9 days later champagne yeast

Answer (score 2):

Fermentability is more realted to the wort than the yeast.  Given what you posted, my bet is that you made a wort high in unfermentables and may not get much more attenuation.

Answer (score 1):

I take it was an extract brew, not AG, so there won't be much of non-fermentables (aka starch).

What was done wrong? Too big OG. Probably no starter. Probably poor wort aeration.

What is wrong now? The op expects the result too soon. I'd normally expect e.g. a beer of OG 1.090 to sit in the fermenter for 2-3 months (with proper aeration and starter!). Gravity drop is not linear function of time, it's more like 80/20 rule.

What can be done to save it now? I'd say, some dilution and krausening. Make a big amount (say, 4 l) of wort with OG 1.030, add yeast, and when fermentation there peaks in activity (I'd say, on the 3rd day), pour it into the big beer. Don't be afraid to oxidize it, the yeast will clean up after you. Leave it for a month or two.

Answer (score 0):

*I tried to post this as a comment on Denny's answer, but it wouldn't let me.*

Take a look at [this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11136/consistently-high-final-gravity) and see if the situation seems familiar. I had trouble with high FG due to poor fermentability of the malt extract I was using.

Answer (score 0):

There's always going to be some unfermentable sugars. If you're mashing, you can try to control that by doing a long mash at low temperature, but if you're using extract, you're probably stuck at a good middle-of-the-road mash, which is going to leave your high gravity beer very sweet at the end.